# How to access Extension method from view context in MVC Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want access **ViewContext** on view because I have created extension method and using that extension I want to access Base Controller on View.

Refer to the code below

```
public static class ViewContextExtension
{       
    public static BaseController BaseController(this ControllerContext view)
    {
        BaseController objBaseController = null;
        if (view != null)
            objBaseController = view.Controller as BaseController;
        return objBaseController;
    }
}
```

I want to use same code in MVC Core 2 but I am not able access it on view side.

Previously I was using it in MVC 5.2.3 E.g.

```
!ViewContext.BaseController().IsMobileDevice
```

Comment: My first question would be Why? because this appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: That information can be passed to the View in a model or in the ViewBag.

Comment: because there is some complex logic in function and i need to display final value by calling function itself and i need in mutliple page and viewbag not recommended for us.

Comment: Why not just literally do: `ViewContext.Controller as BaseController` in your view. This extension method doesn't really do much for you. However, there's really no reason you should ever need to upcast like this. Assuming your controller inherits from `BaseController`, there's nothing you can do with `BaseController` that you couldn't also do directly with your controller instance. Why do you think you need to upcast?

Comment: ViewContext.Controller is not available in .NetCore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution for above question. refer below.

**Use Name library.**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

**Find code below**

```
public static class ControllerContextExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// BaseController
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="view"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>

        public static BaseController BaseController(this ControllerContext view)
        {
            var factory = CreateControllerFactory();
            return factory.CreateController(view) as BaseController;
        }
        private static DefaultControllerFactory CreateControllerFactory()
        {
            var propertyActivators = new IControllerPropertyActivator[]
            {
                  new DefaultControllerPropertyActivator(),
            };

            return new DefaultControllerFactory(
                new DefaultControllerActivator(new TypeActivatorCache()),
                propertyActivators);
        }
    }
```

**Access above code in view as below .cshtml.**

```
controllerContext.BaseController().IsMobileDevice
```

Suggest if we can improve above code. Happy coding.